# How would I run Django and LAMP on different subdomains, but on the same Apache server?

Tags: ubuntu, php, apache-httpd, django

I am currently working on a development project where I need to run four different PHP programs (both with MySQL backends) and one Django project.

Current Plan:

- XenForo (forums.domain.com) [PHP Forum]
- OSQA (qa.domain.com) [Django/Python QA Site]
- PHPFox (social.domain.com) [PHP Social Network]
- BugTrackr (bugs.domain.com) [PHP Bug Tracker, custom made]
- Wordpress (www.domain.com) [PHP CMS]

How would this be possible so that they could all coexist on the same Apache, play nice with each other, and not crash the system every *n* hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For django**, I think you need to use `mod_proxy` in Apache and create a `VirtualHost`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName qa.domain.com
     ProxyPreserveHost on
     ProxyPass / http://localhost:DJANGO_PORT_HERE/
</VirtualHost>
```

*Don't forget to uncomment the `mod_proxy`/`mod_proxy_http` in `httpd.conf`*

For the other applications, just create a simple `VirtualHost` too.

---

The **django documentation** recommend you use the `mod_wsgi`, adding this in your `httpd.conf`:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

---

Comment: Thank you. As of now, I cannot test this method, but I hopefully will soon.